# How to detect whether clipboard.js is supported or not

Tags: javascript, clipboard, clipboard.js

Using clipboard plugin http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/
Can I know programmatically whether this plugin is supported or not on the running browser? The idea is I want to hide the 'copy to clipboard' button if the plugin is not supported. Something like

```
if(clipboard is not supported) {
    $('.copy-btn').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`document.queryCommandSupported`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandSupported) the required underlying command

```
if (!(document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported('copy'))) {
    $('.copy-btn').hide();
}
```

Comment: document.queryCommandSupported('copy') is always false in chrome!

Comment: @coure2011 please see the [**known bugs**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en#known-bugs) about this, it is not _always_ false, e.g. test `document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {console.log(document.queryCommandSupported('copy'))})` will cause `true` to log after a click

Comment: Further, by [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476508) it looks like _Google Chrome's_ implementation will have these bugs fixed in v48.0.2541.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.queryCommandSupported`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandSupported) but there are some known bugs. That's why I recommend using this [polyfill](https://github.com/zenorocha/document.queryCommandSupported).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the browser version is greater than or equal to those mentioned in the "Browser Support" section.

https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js#browser-support

Comment: Checking for browser is generally a bad idea. They change. It's much better to use feature support checking. i.e. is this feature available here.